# Not all of my controllers put the data in $scope

Tags: angularjs

Why will only three of my controllers (Books, hikes, and side nav links) return data and none of the other will. I have put the code on plunker - plnkr.co/edit/dRgckZijLTe5CPH1Z8OE

This is what it looks like on the web - http://www.xtrane.com/ajs/caches.php

Comment: I can see only two controllers have been used in your HTML, is the code on plunker complete?

Comment: To begin no I did not add all of the pages. I just now added the book.php page which works fine. I have only been able to get data from 3 of the 5 controllers. The two that do not work are the geocacheCtrl which I use in the index.html page and the photoCtrl which is used on another page. If I run the controller file by itself in the browser I see the data returned in JSON format. Take a look http://www.xtrane.com/ajs/dCaches.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some of the DB fields had some carriage returns before the data. And, all double quotes had to be removed from any text

Not sure why it cannot ignore the double quotes or how you get the JSON object to not throw an error on everyone it encounters.